# Specific Internal Energy Decreases with Increasing Pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics

I was looking at "Properties of Compressed Liquid Water" (Table A-5) in Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics by Moran. Table A-5 shows that the specific internal energy $u$ of compressed liquid water decreases as as the pressure increases at a fixed temperature. For instance, $u=418.24$ kJ/kg at $T = 100$ F and $P = 2.5$ MPa. While $u=412.08$ kJ/kg at $T = 100$ F and $P = 25$ MPa. Also, this same trend in specific internal energy is shown in [Table 3. Compressed Water and Superheated Steam](http://www.nist.gov/srd/upload/NISTIR5078-Tab3.pdf). This trend that the specific internal energy decreases with increases pressure goes completely against my intuition and the numerous examples of compressing a gas or two phase mixture in a cylinder with a piston. Any thoughts on how the internal energy is decreasing?

Answer (score 0):

If dealing with a gas, the internal energy must be reduced with increasing pressure, as the temperature will be constant and the gas will be more compact.
Also see the P-T diagram of water, when changing pressure keeping the temperature constant, the vapor phase will change to liquid phase or solid phase which have less energy than a vapor phase.